# How to find the clientside control in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, html

i have a table in the content page.I'm unable to access this control from my codebehind. I'm trying to convert the content to an xml file 
 `Table tbSelectedColumns = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("selectedColumns") as Table;`
is not working. Please help. My table is within a div control with id "test".

Comment: What does your page (.aspx) look like?

Comment: it's having a format like <contentplaceholder><div><table> <rows and columns generated dynamically/> </table></div></contentplaceholder>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `<table>` instead of `<asp:table>` you will need to add a `runat="server"` to the table tag. ie `<table runat="server">`

However if you need to access the table via client side Javascript ASP.Net will change the name.

If you do need to do client side Javascript check this blog for a solution.
http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/ShowPost.aspx?id=252178

Comment: What i want to do is to save the contents of this client side table to an xml using a button click(button control should runat server). can u tell me how  that is possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Are you trying to something with AJAX?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ajax. All i know is im lost. How can i save the table which is not a server control, to an xml file? is there any way to convert a portion of the aspx page to xml file?

Comment: I have never done any real AJAX before, I use the ASP.Net update panel as speed of development is more import than the speed of the web site in my current role :-/ but I think the best bet will be to use the solution provided in the link above and JQuery. A quick Google search I found this that might help http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/10/10/jquery-and-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to use asp.net code for this.  Possibly a GridView.  This will allow you to access your dynamically created content.

Then to store this data on button click you could use something similar to this:

```
protected void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(MapPath("output.xml"), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    foreach(DataRow row in DataGrid.Rows)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString());
    }
    writer.Close();
}
```

Something like this would write what you need to file.  WriteElementString(xmlTagName, xmlContent);

Comment: This should be done with pure html. That's why i followed this method.

Comment: What is the point of using an asp.net command FindControl on standard html?

Comment: That's right. I thought of that only now. Is there any other workaround? My objective is to drag and drop some text to a div in the placeholder and form it into a table . I need to sort and move the elements within the table. And finally to save this to an xml. The final step, i dont know how.

Comment: The reason to use client side Javascript is because ASP.Net does a page post back which is a lot slower.